# JavaScript - Image gallery - Slide left and right

Tags: javascript, html, css, image-gallery

I have a responsive image gallery that currently displays thumbnails on a page, which when clicked, will enlarge the image and open it up as a modal.

The limitations of this code are that when I have opened up the image, I have to press the 'X' button, and go back to the thumbnails in order to open up another image.

What I would like, is that when the modal opens up, with the enlarged image, there is a '<' and '>' button that allows you to scroll through the enlarged images.

Any ideas how this can be done?

I hope this was clear, if not then it will make more sense when you view it as a working example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_image_gallery_responsive_js).

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Dude, Google is your friend, just search for "Image slider with prev/next button in JavaScript/JQuery....", you will find thousands of results.

Comment: include YOUR OWN CODE in your question and please refrain from posting links

Answer (score 0):

Supposing the image which is being displayed at the moment is pic1 and that you have pic2, pic3, pic4 as well.
First you need to create an array in javascript containing the location of these files. Now assuming that the id of that image is "mainpic".

```
var a=['pic1','pic2'....'pic4'];
var l=a.length;
var currentpic=0;
function changeright(){
    documnet.getElementById("mainpic").src=++window.currentpic%window.l;
    }
function changeleft(){
    document.getElementById("mainpic").src=abs(--window.currentpic%window.l);
   }
```

Now for the html part you need too superimpose these signs-
    <> which you can do by using position:absolute and z index:-1. You can find the examples on w3school.
 It should be something like
  <aaaaaaa

And in css

```
enter code here
     #superimpose{
 position:absolute/relative;
 top:100px//or some other value to move the text over the pic or use "left"        and "right"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), I used it at work and it is really good.